# Launch PhpStorm with the command line using terminal

Tags: terminal, phpstorm

I'm looking to launch PhpStorm via the command line in linux

```
pstorm
```

I have read up on the topic and have seen countless suggestions pointing to "Create command-line launcher" and have messed with it extensively.

I always end up with:

```
pstorm: command not found
```

My PATH

```
 /home/hutber/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin:/usr/share/PhpStorm-213.6777.58/bin:/home/hutber/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/hutber/.local/bin:/home/hutber/.fzf/bin
```

Anyone out there done this successfully? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to simply run Tools | Create Command-line Launcher that would do that for you? If that doesn't work for you see how to do that manually at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#standalone

Comment: I did ye. Sorry I should have said. I did this as root and also my local user. Neither worked. Brilliant though, the command found in the link fixed it :D